# Label shows 2 text values on refresh

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have a label that shows a status. I update the status using this function which get a number from 0 to 3 from my database.

the label is declared as weak:

```
@IBOutlet weak var dealProgressLabel: UILabel!
```

then

```
func updateDealStatus(){

    dealProgressActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
    api.loadDealDetails(dealIdent!, completionHandler: { (status, error ) -> Void in

        if error != nil{

            print(error)
        }
        else{
            if let dealStatusProgr = status{

                print("deal status is now\(dealStatusProgr)")
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                    self.setDealProgressStatusLabel(Int(dealStatusProgr)!)
                    self.dealProgressActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
                }
            }

        }
    })
}
```

then I just use a switch to change the text label:

```
func setDealProgressStatusLabel(dealProgress: Int){


    switch dealProgress {

    case 0:

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){

        self.dealProgressLabel.text =  "Waiting for Payment"
        self.dealProgressLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.paymentButton

        }



    case 1:

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){

            self.dealProgressLabel.text = "Waiting to Redeem"
            self.dealProgressLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
            //  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.disputeButton
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil

        }



    case 2:
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){

            self.dealProgressLabel.text = "Waiting for Review"
            self.dealProgressLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.addReviewButton

        }


    case 3:


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){

            self.dealProgressLabel.text = "Completed"
            self.dealProgressLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil


        }



    default:


        self.dealProgressLabel.text = ""


    }

}
```

The problem is that, if I process the payment, the label correctly shows the next status "waiting to Redeem". 
[image]

However when I refresh the tableView with:

```
func reloadModelWhenPull(sender:AnyObject){
    updateDealStatus()
}
```

both text "waiting for payment" and "waiting to redeem" are shown one on top of each other.

[image]

When I pull again, "waiting for payment" disappeared.

```
print("deal status is now\(dealStatusProgr)")
```

always shows the correct status number so I don't  know what do to anymore.

Lastly, I call `updateDealStatus` in `viewWillAppear`

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    updateDealStatus()
}
```

***************************************UPDATE***************

I kept refreshing and I found out that the problem happen for approximately the first 60/90 seconds or so. After that it always shows only the correct text? 
Any idea?

***************************************UPDATE2***************

if I wait approximately 10 second before I pull refresh the problem doesn't happen. If I can start refreshing immediately then it happen indefinetely

Answer (score 0):

```
func setDealProgressStatusLabel(dealProgress: Int){

            self.dealProgressLabel.text = "" //Empty as method starts
            ...
}
```

It will set "" before assigning new value.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately is still happening. Please see updated question with pictures.

Comment: Is your dealProgressLabel label is strong by property, if so, make it weak.@mat

Comment: I tried that and honestly I thought that was the right answer but it's still happening on refresh

Comment: I need to check make it at my end to know exact reason, I will check it later.

Comment: Thanks. Please see updated question. The problem happens for the first 90 seconds or so. After that it always shows the correct text when I refresh.

Comment: So, try to use         [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:90.0]; after              self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.addReviewButton
  and let me know.

Comment: ONE MORE THING, WHY ARE YOU USING dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), IF you can directly put code inside switch, will work more efficiently. @mat

Comment: if I wait approximately 10 second before I hit refresh the problem doesn't happen. If I can keep refreshing immediately then it happen!

Comment: I agree, but still you should not do this calculation in main threat, do it normally. it will be fine.

Comment: But to update the UI I have to do it in main threat. right?

Answer (score 0):

I just changed this and it works:

```
 let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
                    // moved my switch here
                    self.setDealProgressStatusLabel(Int(dealStatusProgr)!)
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                        print(dealStatusProgr)
                        self.dealProgressActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                        self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
                    }

                }
```

[this](https://thatthinginswift.com/background-threads/)  point me to the right direction.